# inverse of sum of a matrix plus its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm trying to show that $$\sup_{x}\{y^Tx - x^TAx\} = y^TA^{-1}y,$$ (where $A$ is positive definite) however I'm having a bit of trouble.

I know I can find the stationary point of the inside of the $\sup$, which gives me $$y^T - x^T(A^T + A) = 0 \implies x = (A^T + A)^{-1}y$$, however at this point I get a little stuck: plugging this back in for $x$ gives me $y^T(A^T + A)^{-1}y - y^T(A^T + A)^{-1}A(A^T + A)^{-1}y$. How do I proceed from here? As far as I know I can't do anything with the inverse-over-sum, but is there a known rule that I'm missing?.

Could someone suggest a good way forward?

Comment: What does it imply that A is positive definite?

Comment: Oh, in the context of the actual homework problem, the function $g(x) = x^TAx$ is a convex function; I think the relevance is that this is the reason I can find the stationary point inside the sup (and be guaranteed that there's only one and it's going to be maximal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A$ is (real) positive definite, $A=A^T$ and hence $(A^T+A)^{-1}=\frac12A^{-1}$.

And the answer you found is wrong. To find the answer using calculus is fine, but you can actually simply complete the square:
$$
y^Tx-x^TAx = \frac14y^TA^{-1}y - \left(A^{1/2}x - \frac12A^{-1/2}y\right)^T \left(A^{1/2}x - \frac12A^{-1/2}y\right).
$$
So the supremum is $\frac14y^TA^{-1}y$ (*not* $y^TA^{-1}y$) and it is attained at $x=\frac12A^{-1}y$.

Comment: Huh, so you're right; completing the square had completely slipped my mind. Thanks for the $A = A^T$ hint too; I knew there was something simple I was missing!